# Implementing a CNN using tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I have a 2-class classification problem in hand. I have extracted a set of 3 features for each training example .. I am planning to use a very simple CNN to learn the weights. My model looks like[image]

I am planning to use tensorflow for implementing this CNN in python. The official tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/ seems to be somewhat abstract . Can I get a basic code to train this?

Comment: Not sure if that's strictly a CNN (no convolutional), but I'd you take a look at to learn.org they have an example that looks very similar to what you are trying to do

Comment: the official tutorial provides a link to the code on github https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68599/755, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/255802/2921. 
 
Crossposts

Add the name of the other site inside the brackets and a link to the other copy of the question inside the parentheses:

[Also posted on ]().
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

The model you're showing isn't convolutional or deep, looks like really all you need is a simple one-layer network with a  nonlinearity -- you could consider something written on top of TensorFlow such as Keras, which is quite simple:
https://keras.io/#getting-started-30-seconds-to-keras

following that short tutorial should actually get you exactly the model you have up there, up to the number of units. .